# Include domain name or not in /etc/hosts?

Tags: networking

I am setting up a VMWare cluster of CentOS nodes. Is it best practice to include a domain name after the machine? What are the potential problems of leaving it out? Does a domain complicate configuration or simplify it?

For example, if my node is at `192.168.1.93`, should I change `/etc/hosts` from

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
```

to

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.cluster localhost
192.168.1.93 computernode1.cluster computenode1
```

or

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
192.168.1.93 computenode1
```

or

```
#127.0.0.1 localhost
192.168.1.93 computenode1
```

or

```
192.168.1.93 localhost
192.168.1.93 computenode1
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Putting the domain name in `/etc/hosts` is optional, and you can run a system without any ill effect at all.

The only downside of leaving it out is that the system's fully qualified hostname won't show up properly. For example, `hostname -f`.

The way detection of the fully qualified host name works:

1. It first gets the hostname, or 'shortname'. This is the output of `uname -n` or `hostname`.
2. It then gets the IP address for that hostname by consulting `/etc/hosts` (or whatever you have in `/etc/resolv.conf`, and falling back to the latter sources if not found in `/etc/hosts`).
3. Once it has the IP it then does a reverse lookup by again consulting `/etc/hosts`.
4. Once it has a record in `/etc/hosts`, the first entry is used as the fully qualified hostname.

In a nutshell, if you want fully qualified hostname to work, you should do either:

```
127.0.0.1 fully.qualified.hostname hostname localhost.localdomain localhost
```

or

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
1.2.3.4 fully.qualified.hostname hostname
```

Comment: I didn't consider that point. Having a fully qualified hostname is useless for a desktop PC, and can be problematic for a laptop (because a laptop is likely to be brought in different networks) but it's useful for a server. Apache2, for example, complains when it cannot determine its FQDN.

Comment: @lgeorget You can also just use `libnss-myhostname` which takes care of resolving your FQDN but doesn't need an entry in `/etc/hsots`

Comment: The configuration above may cause problems, see [this](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=247734#27) discussion on Debian’s current practice of setting up the `hosts` file, and [this](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2005/10/msg00559.html) one on the usage (or lack thereof) of the `localhost.localdomain` entry.

Comment: `sudo` also complains if hostname is not in `/etc/hosts`: `sudo: unable to resolve host <hostname>`

Comment: These steps showed my obvious mistake, a typo in the hostname! This grep showed it up instantly `grep $(hostname) /etc/hosts` If that doesn't return your `/etc/hosts` entry then check your entries. The IP returned needs to match `ip -br -4 a | grep -Ev "^lo"`

Answer (score 3):

As long as your host agrees with your domain name, specifying it or not in `/etc/hosts` won't change anything. Another practice is to have it specified as the `domain` parameter in `/etc/resolv.conf`. Not specifying it could simplify your life if, one day, your network administrator changes it. Specifying it doesn't change anything, as far as I know.

You should definitely leave `127.0.0.1 localhost` or `127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain` in `/etc/hosts`. Some applications could start having a really strange behaviour is `localhost` binds to anything other than your loopback address because this is a really, really, unexpected setting.

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify fully qualified domain name in the first position after IP address.

As we read in `man 5 hosts`:

> For each host a single line should be present with the following information:
>
> IP_address canonical_hostname [aliases...]

If not following the rule, then some software may break. For example, Puppet configuration management system may start changing your hostname back and forth on each run just because you did not specify domain part or because you put alias without domain on the line before FQDN.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is really "optional" (as Patrick indicated above). I just finally tracked down a problem with nfs permissions reverting to nobody:nobody. It looks like for permissions to properly work with nfs mounts (using idmapd), the domain name of the server has to match the domain name of the client exactly. From some docs I found -- `hostname -f` minus the actual hostname has to be identical between client and server OR you have to specify a domain name for the client in `/etc/idmapd.conf`, which means each client.

Is there an official rule about where to specify domain name? The `domainname` command doesn't seem to pick it up out of /etc/hosts.. so putting in /etc/hosts bothers me, since it means it's stored in multiple locations on the filesystem..