# Should /etc/hosts contain an entry for the FQDN that maps to a loopback address?

Tags: debian, hosts

We have a Debian 8.2 system `foo` provided by our IT department for production. Its `/etc/hosts` file contains these two lines:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       foo.example.com   foo
```

This maps the FQDN of the system to `127.0.1.1`, while the real IP address of the system is `10.5.1.38` (which is *not* given in `hosts`).

Is this correct or should `/etc/hosts` *not* contain the FQDN?

Note that the system is networked, has access to DNS and `nslookup` with the FQDN gives the correct IP address (`10.5.1.38`).

Comment: This has been discussed [before](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77917/include-domain-name-or-not-in-etc-hosts), but overall, answers here are largely opinion-based.

Comment: As I said in my answer, I have already seen real world problems due to this practice - this is more than an opinion. While it can be used in testing environments, I do not recommend using it in production environments. Cheers

Comment: Is the second IP intended to be .0.1?

Comment: @JeffSchaller: No. It really is `.1.1`.

Comment: @ThomasDickey: I'm looking for best practice here.

Comment: Then read where it's been discussed [before](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77917/include-domain-name-or-not-in-etc-hosts), in greater detail. Reopening an old issue only attracts me-too's, which don't add useful information.

Comment: @ThomasDickey: This question is really about the wisdom of having a loopback address with the fqdn in hosts.

Comment: I'm aware of that.  You should have noticed that there were no useful answers.

Comment: Your system's IP address is not 10.5.1.38, it may have an interface which such an address, but it also has another one (lo) with 127.0.0.1 (or any address within `127.0/8`) several IPv6 ones and potentially others. The FQdN should resolve to a network address which a host can use to contact your machine. That may be 10.5.1.38 from a machine on the local subnet attached to that interface of your machine, 3.4.5.6 from the internet, but for the machine itself, a most obvious one is one on the loopback subnet. It's better for 127.0.0.1 to reverse-resolve to "localhost" though, hence the 127.0.1.1

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Agreed. In *this* case the machine has a loopback interface with 127.0.0.1 and an `eth0` with `10.5.1.38` (and a local ipv6).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I regard this as a bad practice, I have seen developers doing that.  While it can be used in testing environments, I do not recommend using it in production environments.

By definition, the kernel has a very defined behaviour for the localhost.

There could be also problems too, I do remember having a service opened to the Internet that was not working, because the developer used the name in a config file, that was pointing to the loopback instead of the public address.

I my opinion your hosts files should be:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
10.5.1.38       foo.example.com   foo
```

Comment: The OP's question had the fqdn on 127.0.1.1, not 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Indeed thanks. This question is on track to be closed nonetheless. Corrected it.