# CentOS 7 hostname netbios/fqdn output

Tags: centos, dns, hostname

I have a CentOS 7 install that is giving me some weird returns when I lookup the hostname of the localmachine. I am used to working with Windows and the hosts file (/etc/hosts in CentOS) so feel like I have this setup correct. I do have a few entries in the hosts file as I am running a group of virtual machines for a test deployment scenario - Hence the extra names defined in there. All the machines in the deployment (3) have the same setup and are returning essentially the same data.

```
admin@node2$ hostname
node2.deployment.local

admin@node2$ hostname -f
chef-node2

admin@node2$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
192.168.5.99 node1 node1.deployment.local
192.168.5.100 master master.deployment.local
192.168.5.98 node2 node2.deployment.local

admin@node2$ printenv | grep -i -e "hostname"
HOSTNAME=node2.deployment.local

admin@node2$ cat /etc/environment
http_proxy=http://stupidproxy.itsaywehavetohaveit.local:3128
https_proxy=http://stupidproxy.itsaywehavetohaveit.local:3128
java_home=/applications/jre1.8.0_92/
DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:0.0
```

What I am trying to figure out is why the system prints the netbios name when running the 'hostname -f' command and prints the FQDN when I run the 'hostname' command. I believe that this is causing me some issue.

Your help understanding and hopefully resolving this is appreciated.

Comment: Is `node2` really in `/etc/hosts` as "deplyment"?

Comment: Sorry - No, I have removed that data and replaced with generic (& poorly spelt ) data. I have corrected that to now be consistent.

Comment: Order matters! You have the entries in `/etc/hosts` backwards. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/77924/4358 (point #4)

Comment: OK - I have the understanding of the order - And it resolves my question (Thanks) - To a degree. How is this effected by an interface that is using DHCP? EG: The hosts file will not automatically update this when the IP Address of the interface changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

swap the hosts in your /etc/hosts, the format should be long then short.

good:

```
176.31.91.220 www.mikejonesey.co.uk mike
```

bad:

```
176.31.91.220 mike www.mikejonesey.co.uk
```

hostname will work off this, also I on epel systems i tend to change the domain in /etc/sysconfig/network to be just the hostname, then add the extra def for domain.

Comment: YES! OK, thank you, the order has resolved the issue. Now, how does this effect a machine that is using DHCP. EG: Should their not be an automatic process somewhere in the system rather than using the hosts file?

Comment: hosts file will override DNS, but won't effect DHCP, if you have a dhcp server and want the ip of the node to not change then you'll need to add a static ip for the node /etc/dhcp/dhcp.conf. if you're talking about pure host resolution on the machine, there is no auto mechanism for this, just config files /etc/sysconfig/network and /etc/hosts (on epel based systems), some unix os also have /etc/hostname (which should not contain the domain), the domain should always be added as a seperate param in /etc/sysconfig/network; `HOSTNAME=bob` and `DOMAIN=example.com` for `bob.example.com`

Comment: OK - I will work with the `/etc/sysconfig/network` file as I don't want to have these systems on static IP' to ensure I replicate the environment correctly.

Answer (score 1):

According to `man hostname`:

```
   -f, --fqdn, --long
          DNS host name or FQDN
```

So `hostname -f` returns the hostname generated by a reverse DNS lookup. `hostname` without any arguments just returns whatever's in `/etc/hostname`.

Comment: Yes, that much I understand (from the `man` output). The issues is that `$ hostname` and `$ hostname -f` are outputting the opposite of what I am expecting. EG: `$ hostname -f` returns the netbios name and not the FQDN.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're asking now.  What do you get when you run `grep hosts /etc/nsswitch.conf`? It's possibly because you have netbios configured as a hostname database.

Comment: The output is as follows:

`$ grep hosts /etc/nsswitch.conf
#hosts:    db files nisplus nis dns
hosts: files dns myhostname`