# How to programattically determine the device name/basename of the root partition?

Tags: linux, block-device, usb-device, root-filesystem

Ref: The following question
[Drive name? What is the correct term for the "sda" part of "/dev/sda"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/392701/drive-name-what-is-the-correct-term-for-the-sda-part-of-dev-sda)

Given:

1. I have a system, (in this case a Raspberry Pi, but this could be relevant to any 'nix system.)
2. It is running a version of Linux and it can be assumed that all normal Linux commands work.
3. The boot device can be either a SD card or a USB attached storage device.
4. If booted from an attached storage device, the device "basename" is sd(x)
5. If booted from a SD card, the device "basename" becomes something like "mm(xxxx)"

What I want to do:
I want to be able to programmatically, (in a shell script if possible) the kind of device it was booted from, and change certain characteristics based on what the boot device is.

Simple example:

```
Boot device = "mmxxxxx"
   Print "Booted from SD card!"
Boot device = "sda"
   Print "Booted from Attached Storage!"
```

What I want to do is extract the, (for want of a better term), major device type the root partition is derived from, (*i.e.* "sd", "mm", or whatever, depending on what device is mounted as the root partition.)

I suspect that I could, somehow, list the device that is mounted on root, ***without listing everything in `mount`***, and then extract the first two letters after the final slash. . .

Comment: "basename" (in the Unix context) means something different than what you're using it for. Can you tell me what you exactly mean with *the device "basename" is sd(x)*, I don't understand that.

Comment: According to the article I referenced above, "basename" is one of two correct descriptions of that part of the fully qualified device name, though I agree that it's absolutely counterintuitive.  My own version, "major device type" is probably also hideous too.

Comment: I really don't understand what you mean. Can you please explain with a concrete example?

Comment: As I said above, depending on the device used to boot the system, the "major device type" is either "mm(xxx)" [/dev/mdxxxxx] or "sdx" [/dev/sdx], depending on the type of device used to boot my system.  What I want is to be able to ask (in a script) "What type of device did I boot from?  "sd" or "mm"?

Comment: `findmnt -nvo SOURCE --mountpoint /` may be a good start.

Comment: None of what you describe is a major device type, Jim! (Major device type, major Device number also already have meanings in Unix). Entering this discussion a bit late, but: Jim, do you really just care about the first two letters of the device name? Or what is the thing you actually want to do with the knowledge you get with this? This feels a lot like you're making assumptions on device names that don't hold, but that's not a real problem, because the things you want to do can be found out differently. That's why I ask.

Comment: And, the author of the question you linked to accepted the answer with the lowest number of people agreeing, and the answer simply got it wrong.

Comment: In my specific case, I have a robot with an e-Ink status display that I can write information to - and one of the things I want to write is "where the O/S is mounted" - either an attached device or via a SD card.  Since the first two letters of the device's designation are sufficient to determine that, that's al I need.  Others might need more, or fewer letters.

Comment: Note that I'm not trying to be pedantic about what you call a specific thing - I just wanted to ask a question about a specific part of the device's name as shown.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Mount point is controlled by systemd.

You can list the systemd mount unit files through:

```
systemctl list-units --type=mount --all
```

sample output:

```
  -.mount                       loaded    active   mounted Root Mount                                   
  boot-efi.mount                loaded    active   mounted /boot/efi
...
```

The Root partition is controlled by `-.mount`.

```
systemctl status -- -.mount

● -.mount - Root Mount
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/fstab; generated)
     Active: active (mounted) since Wed 2024-02-07 
      Where: /
       What: /dev/sdaX
       Docs: man:fstab(5)
             man:systemd-fstab-generator(8)
```

To extract device name :

```
systemctl status -- -.mount |grep -oP '(?<=What: ).*' |xargs basename
```

Better, as pointed [@steeldriver](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/65304/steeldriver) in this [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/768756/how-to-programattically-determine-the-device-name-basename-of-the-root-partition/768761?noredirect=1#comment1467532_768761):

```
systemctl show --value --property=What -- -.mount |xargs basename
```

man `systemd.mount`:

> `What:` Takes an absolute path of a device node, file or other resource to mount.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
Unfortunately, I am not sure what you mean by "what".  How would I apply that to asking the musical question "what's the [whatever you want to call it] name of the device mounted as root?  In my case, it would be "sd" or "mm" depending on where the root filesystem is mounted - /dev/sd(x)  or /dev/mm(xxxx)

Comment: So in this case, '(?<=What: ).*', "What" returns that particular part of the listing, (What: /dev/sdaX), right?

Comment: Works like a champ!  The only thing left is to grep out the two characters I need.

Comment: @JimJRHarris : the explanation of the `(?<=What:)` regex construc: https://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html and 1) choose on top (under the title) the proper regex engine you are using (I selected : `Perl`, and `GNU ere` (=egrep), but they all differ and offer more or less features and have different syntaxes  : choose the proper one) and then 2) look for the line "positive lookbehind": it allows one to specify what NEEDS to be found before the rest of the regex, and that part is not "captured" in the regex (it just serves as context). That site is a gold mine for regex informations.

Comment: (corrected) : You may want : `grep -Po '(?<=What: /dev/)..'` to get the first 2 chars following the `What: /dev/xxxxx` line ? `-P` is an option available on GNU grep and invokes the Perl regex engine. test: `echo "abc: /dev/aabb" | grep -Po '(?<=abc: /dev/)..'`

Answer (score 6):

Here's a Linux answer that doesn't rely on *systemd* (requires `/sys` mounted for `lsblk` use and also the `jq` command to parse results).

Knowing that `lsblk` already includes all the logic to figure out the dependencies in its tree output, I wondered how it could be leveraged for the task. Using `--inverse` displays leafs first (but yet doesn't enable to give a leaf as argument), in order to filter with the `/` mount point first. Then with `--json` one can iterate to find the result.

It outputs the final device name, bypassing any layer of LVM, LUKS etc. (tested with a system using / over LV over LUKS in a partition of the disk). Not tested with RAID (where I would expect multiple devices to be output, or this `jq` script to fail).

That's a single long line:

```
lsblk --json --tree --inverse | jq -r '.blockdevices[] | if .mountpoints[] == "/" then ( .. | if .children? then empty else if .name then .name else empty end end ) else empty end'
```

or more easy to read:

```
lsblk --json --tree --inverse |
    jq -r '
.blockdevices[] |
    if .mountpoints[] == "/" then
        .. |
            if .children? then
                empty
            else
                .name // empty
            end
    else
        empty
    end
'
```

It takes the first match for `/` and will recurse (with `..`) over objects, until they don't include anymore a children object (also named `"children"`, the only kind of child), meaning it's the target device, and then display its name.

To get only the 2 first characters of the result, just append an additional  `| cut -c-2`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `df /` to get the device for `/`.
You can filter by column (`--output=source`) and row (`tail -1`), too:

```sh
% df --output=source / | tail -1
/dev/mapper/sys-root
```

Answer (score 2):

All of the previously posted answers are wrong; until less than a year ago none of them would have worked on my system reliably.¹

Fundamentally the problem is you need the stable name of the device not the name of a device that would access it on this boot. Because of dynamic minor allocation, these aren't the same thing.

This works:

```
ROOTDEV=`grep '^[^ ]* / ' /proc/mounts | sed 's/ .*$//'`
if [ "$ROOTDEV" = /dev/root ]
then    ROOTDEV=`sed 's/^.* root=\([^ ]*\).*$/\1/' /proc/cmdline`
fi
case "$ROOTDEV" in
UUID=*) ROOTDEV=/dev/disk/by-uuid/${ROOTDEV#UUID=}
esac
```

What this does is extract the correct device name from /proc where it was preserved from being mounted by initrd, and if it's not there gets it from the kernel's command line.

If it's still /dev/root after that you have some ancient system, and `/dev/root` should be correct. It was a symbolic link to the correct root partition in those days. The device major/minor numbers are patched into the kernel binary either at build time or by Lilo, and the system does not have dynamic boot pathways unless it was booted from removable media, in which / is a ramdisk and asking the question doesn't make sense.

¹Systemd's status is borked and yields the wrong answer. Scanning /dev for a device node that matches repeats systemd's bug (I actually found the bug but could not fix it) and returns some device node that has the correct major/minor but won't be correct on the next boot.

The lsblk command has a hard time with multipath.

The problem I've had with df its tendency to return something that works on this boot but not the next boot. I don't know why df has this problem only for the root device but it's been problematic for ages.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way. I have only test this on my own box and your mount command may have a different output.

```
boot_device=( $(mount | grep boot) )
if [[ $(echo "${boot_device[0]}" | grep -c sd) -eq 1 ]]
then
echo "Booted from attached storage"
else 
echo "Booted from SD card!"
fi
```

You could, instead of else, use an elif construct, for instance:

```
elif [[ $(echo "${boot_device[0]}" | grep -c mm) -eq 1 ]]
then
echo "Booted from SD card!"
else
echo "ERROR: Something has gone horribly wrong!"
fi
```

You've already accepted an answer, but since I spent a few minutes figuring out how to do this with the mount command, I'm posting it as an answer.